# Hide and show not working as expected

Tags: jquery

I am trying to show the the div id = #valError below the login form whenever validation is unsuccessful. Below is the code.

But, I can only see the form permanently on the page and the value of the id #valError appearing and disappearing.I want to show it permanently whenever validation fails.
Note: (Both the #valError div and form id=#userForm are under #userFormDiv).

Also, I am removing the #userFormDiv when the validation is successful and show the json response data.

Kinldy help me. Also, suggest me if this the right approach.

```
$.ajax({
            url : "/RestTest/rest/getJson",
            type : "POST",
            dataType : "json",
            data : inputdata,
            contentType : "application/json",
            cache : false,
            async:false,
            beforeSend : function() {
                $("#userForm").hide();
                $("#loadingImg").show();
            },
            success : function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                if(data.invalidCred) {
                    alert(data.invalidCred);
                    $("#loadingImg").remove();
                    $("#userForm").show();
                    $("#valError").show();
                }else {
                    alert(data.SessionID);
                    $("#userFormDiv").remove();
                    $("#responseDiv").show().append(
                            "<ul><li>" + data.OperatorID
                            + "</li><li>" + data.SessionID
                            + "</li></ul>");
                }
            },

<div id="userFormDiv">

<form id="userForm" method="POST">

<table>

    <tr>

        <td><label for="uname">Username:&nbsp;</label></td>
        <td><input name="uname" id="unameID" type="text" title="" placeholder="username" required autofocus/></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><label for="pname">Password:&nbsp;</label></td>
        <td><input name="pname" id="pwdID" type="password" title=""
            placeholder="password" required /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
        <button type="submit" id="LoginID">Login</button>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>



</form>

<img id ="loadingImg" src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." ></img>
<div id="valError">
<p> Authentication failed. Please try again..</p>
</div>
</div>


<div id="responseDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Try to post a JSFIDDLE example..

Comment: only when you show the html code it is possible to solve your problem

Comment: @Saurabh.. I have edited and added the html code.

Comment: JSFIDDLE Link: http://jsfiddle.net/yxW8L/

Answer (score 0):

for issue w.r.t your container #userFormDiv, i would suggest hiding it on DOM(no need for `$("#userForm").hide();` in `beforeSend` .

in your DOM:

```
<div id="userFormDiv" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I dont want to hide when the page loads completes. When I submits the form, I want to hide the form, show the loading image upon receiving the success response I want to show response data.And upon unsuccessful response show the login form with underline error message. Hope I am clear

Comment: @Ashu then please review your post and describe exactly what you want. So you can prevent missunderstandings.

Comment: @reporter Here is the JSFiddle link:jsfiddle.net/yxW8L Please help me guide. I am trying to show the error div under the login form upon unsuccessful validation response from the server. But this is not happening.I am seeing the login form and error div appearing quickly and then disappearing.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your link at Jsfiddle, I **think** I could find the source of your trouble.

It is a common mistake with the methods `.show()` and `.hide()`. As a matter of fact the first method adds the style declaration `visibility:visible` and the second one adds `visibilty:hidden` to an element (or the IE `visibilty:hide`).

The style declarations `display:block` and `display:none` have a different effect. These methods adds to and removes an element from the DOM at runtime. So a use of `.show()` and `.hide()` won't have any effect of this element.

In your css declaration you used `display:none`. And what can you do? try following steps:

1. Create an extra css class with only `display:none` and another one with `display:block`. Then remove the others from `#loadingImg {}`, `#valError {}` and `#1responseDiv {}`.
2. Remove the calls `.show()` and `.hide()` and use `.removeClass().addClass()` instead, always together.
3. You declared your form without any target. Due to this fact you have to add `return false;` as the last statement, within onSubmit function, else the same page will be reloaded.